# How can I re-quantize the dynamic range of an image in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, image-processing, quantization

I need to uniformly re-quantize the dynamic range of an image based on the following pixel value conversions:

```
Pixel Value: Quantized Value
0 - 64     : 31
65 - 128   : 95
129 - 192  : 159
193 - 255  : 223
```

I want to replace all the pixel values in the above ranges with the quantized values. How can I code this in MATLAB?

Comment: One small thing I noticed: your ranges don't cover the same number of pixel values. If you want 64 pixel values per range, you should use these limits: 0-63, 64-127, 128-191, and 192-255.

Comment: Oh, thank you. I also have another question. I want to calculate the probability that each intensity value appears in the image. Is there a way in Matlab that I can determine so? For instance, how many times 31 appears, how many times 95 appears, and so on...

Comment: @user730255: Looks like you already got your answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5985395/matlab-determine-the-probability-of-an-intensity-value). ;)

Comment: Ahaha, yes. It was helpful and so are you! I appreciate it very much, sir.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way is to use [logical indexing](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/math/f1-85462.html#bq7egb6-1). Given a image matrix `img` (which could be [2-D grayscale or 3-D RGB](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/creating_plots/f2-10709.html)), this will replace all your values:

```
img(img >= 0 & img <= 64) = 31;
img(img >= 65 & img <= 128) = 95;
img(img >= 129 & img <= 192) = 159;
img(img >= 193 & img <= 255) = 223;
```

Another option is to create a 256-element look-up table and use the values in your image as indices into this table:

```
lookupTable = [31.*ones(1,65) 95.*ones(1,64) 159.*ones(1,64) 223.*ones(1,63)];
img = uint8(lookupTable(double(img)+1));
```

Note that with this solution you will have to be mindful of the class of your image matrix. Many images are of class `uint8`, spanning values 0 to 255. To use these values as an index you have to convert them to a class that can store larger integers (like `double`) to avoid saturation at the maximum value of 255, then add one since you need an index from 1 to 256. You would then want to convert the resulting image matrix back to class `uint8`.