# Matlab - Determine the probability of an Intensity Value

Tags: matlab, probability

How do you determine the probability that an intensity value appears in an image in Matlab or is there some other way to determine it? The mathematical equation is

```
Pr = Nk / M*N
```

Where Pr is the probability, Nk is number of times that a Kth intensity appears in the image. M*N represents the MxN image.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming your intensity values are all integers, you can do what you want as

```
Pr=nnz(img(:)==value)/numel(img);      %# here img is your image, value is the intensity
```

What the above code does is it checks which element of `img` equals `value` and returns a Boolean vector that is `1` if true and `0` if false. `nnz` is a function that returns the number of non-zero elements (in this case, instances where the condition is true). This is then divided by `numel(img)`, where the function `numel` gives the number of elements in the image.

However, if your values are not integers, then you will have to implement the equality check within a certain tolerance limit, `tol`, as

```
Pr=nnz(img(:)<=value+tol & img(:)>=value-tol)/numel(img);
```